# logstash 2.2.2 hang "Logstash startup completed" while import csv file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am running Elasticsearch 2.2.0 and Logstash 2.2.2 on Windows 2008R2 server as well as Windows 7 workstation.

Using Logstash to import file and MS SQL Server 2008R2 data doesn’t work. (same script and configuration file works fine with Logstash 1.5.4)

Symptom:

1. Import csv file. Logstash hang after “Logstash startup completed”, found one similar issue (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-2-2-0-hangs-at-logstash-startup-completed-while-attempting-to-ingest-csv/41639) but tried re-install JDK doesn’t help.
2. Import MS SQL Server data, logstash ran without error, index created but 0 document imported.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems that the newest version of ELK is the problem.
It used to work for me with Elastic version 2.1.1, kibana 4.3.1 and logstash 2.1.0

Comment: I tried logstash 2.1.0 works fine, but 2.2.0 and 2.2.2 both didn't work. I figure out SQL Server import is my logstash configuration issue which is fixed now.